# Eclipse_getting error while runing the code

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\monikaj\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1748304442\testng-customsuite.xml
SKIPPED: loginEligibility
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:162)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:430)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1270)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:985)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)

Comment: You can't simply post an error message and expect users to answer if they haven't a clue what you are trying to do.Try to explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: Please provide a code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the NullPointerException, we must ensure that all the objects are init properly, before you use them. When we declare a reference variable, we must verify that object is not null, before we request a method or a field from the objects.